# tmux - universal shortcut to make the pane bigger

Tags: tmux

Tmux has:

```
:resize-pane -D (Resizes the current pane down)
:resize-pane -U (Resizes the current pane upward)
:resize-pane -L (Resizes the current pane left)
:resize-pane -R (Resizes the current pane right)
```

If you're in the bottom pane and "resize pane up" your window gets bigger.
If you're in the top pane and you "resize pane up" your window gets smaller.

I would like to create a shortcut like `C-a +` that would just make the currently selected window one row larger, reguardless of whether that means moving the current pane up or down...

I'm not much of a TMUX expert so would really appreciate some help on this :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you want.

Add this to your tmux config file :

```
bind-key -n C-S-Up resize-pane -U 15
bind-key -n C-S-Down resize-pane -D 15
bind-key -n C-S-Left resize-pane -L 25
bind-key -n C-S-Right resize-pane -R 25
```

source: http://www.mattjmorrison.com/today-i-learned/2014/09/25/learned.html